# Domain and range of composite function

Tags: functions

> Suppose $f(x) = e^{3x-2}, x \geq 3$ and $g(x) = x + 3, x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I Want to find the domain of $fg(x)$.

My logic:

Now $f(x)$ can only take values of $x \geq 3$, so I must restrict $x + 3 \geq 3$ so $x \geq 0$. Hence the domain of $fg(x)$ is $x \geq 0$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the domain of the composite function

$$( f \circ g )(x)=f(g(x))$$

one can follow these two steps

1. Find the domain of the inside (input) function.
2. Construct the composite function. Find the domain of this new function. If there are restrictions on this domain, add them to the restrictions from Step 1. If there is an overlap, use the more restrictive domain (or the intersection of the domains).

In your case, the domain of the inside function $g(x)=x+3$ is all real numbers while the domain of $f(x)$ is $x\geq 3$. Therefore, the domain of the composition $f(g(x))=f(x+3)$ is $x+3 \geq 3$ which after subtracting $3$ from both sides forms $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

That's right since $f$ is defined only for arguments greater than $3.$

Comment: But f cannot take values less than 3?? So how does f(2) make sense coming from fg(-1)

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove See edit.